# Facebook chat profile picture (next to the speech bubble icon with dots) is showing up blurred

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Here is what the normal profile picture in Facebook chat looks like:

[image: chat profile with no blur]

But what or why is the little bit of blur showing on the profile picture (not the speech balloon with dots) in this next image?

[image: facebook chat image with blurring]

I'm using the Facebook chat on Windows 7 desktop and it's on the profile picture on the chat icon.

It sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't. I think it started to occur recently over the past week or so.

I'm not sure what they're doing when it happens, but I believe it lasts until the user is done typing.

Comment: Would you be more specific. What platform? I don't see any transparency that you refer to.

Comment: @slybloty Windows 7 desktop and it's on the profile picture on the chat icon. (Fine I'll show you a normal one then instead

Comment: How often does it happen? I've never seen that on my end.

Comment: @slybloty I dunno it sometimes happens sometimes doesn't really. I think it started to occur recently over the past week or so

Comment: The only time I notice a blurring is when the other person sends the message and I receive it. But this lasts for a split second. How long does it last on your end?

Comment: Yeah I'm not too sure on that because I didn't focus on the detail. Actually it lasts until he/she is done typing I believe.

Comment: Do you mean the black dot or that the image looks faded out as well?

Comment: The black dot is just censoring the person's avatar. The fading out is really what it happens with the avatar.

Answer (score -1):

It is an indication that the other person involved in chat is typing.

Comment: Updated an image to compare. Notice how the first image is blurry but the second one is not? They're both typing btw.

Comment: Ok tats weird !!